# Date conversion code behaving different on different machines

Tags: linux, docker, date, go

I have the below code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    loc := "Jan 06"
    date := "2020-12-31 16:00:00 +0000 UTC"
    layout := "2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700 MST"
    t, err := time.Parse(layout, date)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print("Error")
    }

    fmt.Println(t)
    GetFormattedDate(t, loc)
}

func GetFormattedDate(date time.Time, layout string) (string, error) {
    
    fmt.Println("\n\n====================================================")
    fmt.Println("time.Now(): ", time.Now())
    fmt.Println("time.Now().Location(): ", time.Now().Location())
    fmt.Println("Converting: ", date)
    configLocale := "Singapore"
    fmt.Println("configLocale: ", configLocale)

    loc, err := time.LoadLocation(configLocale)
    fmt.Println("loc: ", loc)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    date = date.In(loc)
    fmt.Println("date.In(loc): ", date)
    fmt.Println("layout: ", layout)
    converted := fmt.Sprintf(date.Format(layout))
    fmt.Println("converted fmt: ", converted)
    fmt.Println("\n\n==================================================")
    return fmt.Sprintf(date.Format(layout)), nil
}
```

When I run it locally I get:

```
====================================================
time.Now():  2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC m=+0.000000001
time.Now().Location():  Local
Converting:  2020-12-31 16:00:00 +0000 UTC
configLocale:  Singapore
loc:  Singapore
date.In(loc):  2021-01-01 00:00:00 +0800 +08 // This is the issue
layout:  Jan 06
converted fmt:  Jan 21


==================================================
```

But when I run the same code on my linux box server, I get:

```
time.Now(): 2020-10-24 09:04:22.256288497 +0000 UTC m=+252.011109438
time.Now().Location(): UTC
Converting: 2020-12-31 16:00:00 +0000 UTC
msg":"configLocale: Singapore
msg":"loc: Singapore
date.In(loc): 2020-12-31 16:00:00 +0000 +0000 // This is the issue
layout: Jan 06
converted fmt: Dec 20
```

What I am trying to do:

I am trying to convert: `2020-12-31 16:00:00 +0000 UTC` into a locale specific date, locale being `Singapore`. My layout is `Jan 06`

For one machine this date converts to `Dec 20` and for another it converts to `Jan 21`

Specifically when I dig deeper, I feel the method `date = date.In(loc)` returns different result on different machines despite setting location to `Singapore` and passing it explicitly, as is evident in the logs.

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/NmmC02rTrhQ)

However on the server commandline:

```
/ # zdump Singapore 
Singapore  Mon Oct 26 02:10:18 2020 +08
```

Any suggestions how do I solve this issue?

Comment: These machines seems to have different timezone data. Fix them.

Comment: @Volker I did not fully grasp the solution you propose.

Comment: I think the timezone data (the data which is used to convert a string like "Singapore" to a offset against UTC. Your local server thinks Singapore is UTC+8, your linux server thinks SIngapore is UTC+0. One or both are wrong. What is your ZONEINFO?

Comment: Make sure the tzdata package (or similar; details depend on the distribution) on your server is up-to-date.

Comment: Thanks guys, I will check against this info with the devops team and see where the mismatch is.

Comment: Here is the result from my zoneinfo: 
`echo $ZONEINFO
/zoneinfo.zip`

Comment: I also added a log line: `env, _ := syscall.Getenv("ZONEINFO")
 logger.Error("Env: ", env)` and it does infact load the `zoneinfo.zip`

Comment: For now I dont have a proper solution, so I have resorted to hardcoding the zone and offset: `time.FixedZone("Asia/Singapore", 8*60*60)` and it works! But I am still exploring the actual reason why the time has no effect on conversion.

Answer (score 3):

It is the value of configLocale.  It needs to be an [IANA Time Zone](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#LoadLocation), "", "UTC", or "Local".  "Singapore" is in the list, however it is one of the very few that doesn't follow the standard format of [Continent/Region](https://techsupport.osisoft.com/Documentation/PI-Web-API/help/topics/timezones/iana.html).  It is an unusual format, so the lookup on the server machine fails the lookup and thus defaults to UTC (without returning an error, which may be a bug), and since Singapore is 8 hours ahead, you end up off by 8 hours.  If you use "Asia/Singapore" for configLocale it will work.

Comment: Hi I have missed to mention I have tried values such as `"Asia/Singapore"` `"Asia/Tokyo"` and `"Europe/Berlin"`  with all of these failing.

Comment: Well I still believe that function call is failing so you might put a breakpoint or some debug output in there.

Comment: Yes one particularly hard thing to do is to put remote debugging on a docker container, corporates seldom allow that. I am chasing devops to allow this. Thanks!

Comment: I also believe its definitely an env issue. Just not able to put my finger on it -- yet!

Comment: Well you can take that same go code, time.LoadLocation, which calls LoadLocationFromTZData, copy the source (https://golang.org/src/time/zoneinfo.go?s=15979:16028#L619), and run the exact same code in a test prog.  Add debug as necessary.

Comment: Thanks Sean, this seems legit. Let me try it!